# Having a button enabled in WPF based on dataview values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a dataview thats binded to a Class called Activity. In the grid there are two columns which are a checkbox column and textbox respectively.

I would like to add code that enables a button if at least one of the checkboxes are checked and one of the textboxes has a certain string. I thought about creating a new Property in the Activity class and binding that to an "isEnabled" property but am not sure that would work since theres no set method that would fire the NotifyPropertyChanged.

Any suggestions?

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"  HeadersVisibility="Column" Margin="0,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="262" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActivity, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enabled">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Using a RelayCommand or DelegateCommand on the Button and add the required Logic to the CanExecute method should do the trick in this case.

Comment: You can use Relay command and check the value of selected property in CanExecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above you could leverage `RelayCommand` to perform this kind of action because it has a `CanExecute` function that is evaluated on its own thus not needing a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event to Enable/Disable the `Button`

Here is a full example showing this working as it can be a bit hard to explain

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="315" Width="258" Name="UI">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"  HeadersVisibility="Column"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActivity, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10,10,10,37" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Column1}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enabled">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}" Content="Is any checked &amp; is any 'Item6' " Margin="10,0,9,10" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code:**

```
namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TestObject> myVar = new ObservableCollection<TestObject>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            MyButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteButtonAction, CanButtonExecute);
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Activities.Add(new TestObject { Column1 = "Item" + i, Enabled = false });
            }
        }

        public ICommand MyButtonCommand { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<TestObject> Activities
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }

        private bool CanButtonExecute()
        {
            return Activities.Any(x => x.Enabled) && Activities.Any(x => x.Column1 == "Item2");
        }

        private void ExecuteButtonAction()
        {
            // button clicked
        }
    }


    public class TestObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _column1;
        private bool _enabled;

        public string Column1
        {
            get { return _column1; }
            set { _column1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return _enabled; }
            set { _enabled = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _execute;
        private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (_canExecute != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                if (_canExecute != null)
                {
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute();
        }
    }

}
```

Result: (is any item checked and is any ite "Item6")

[image] [image]